# vb.net converting Latin letters to Russian in textbox

Tags: vb.net, ascii

I would like to be able to convert all Latin letters in textbox to, let's say Russian letters. That's not translating but rather converting "s to с" or "r to R" and so on.

So, user paste latin text to textbox, and after clicking "convert" button, all letters should be converted to other letters.

Any idea?

Some code:

```
Private Sub ConvertingToKiril()
    Try
        If TextBox1.Text.Contains("a") Then
            TextBox1.Text.Replace("a", "c")
        End If
        If TextBox1.Text.Contains("b") Then
            TextBox1.Text.Replace("b", "y")
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex)
    End Try
    End Sub
```

Comment: 1) create a dictionary to map Latin characters to Cyrillic (e.g. "A" → "А", "B" → "Б", etc.). 2) split the input string up into individual characters. 3) apply the mapping to each character. 4) join the individual characters back again.

Comment: It sounds like you want [transliteration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transliteration). Using "transliteration" as a search term might help you find more sophisticated and satisfactory algorithms.

Comment: Tom Blodget that's exactly what I was looking for! Thanks! :)